# Couldn't resolve host 'www.youtube.com

Tags: php, curl

```
$curl = curl_init("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bgn7n3OPAqE&format=json");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);
print_r($ret);
 $err     = curl_errno( $curl );
$errmsg  = curl_error(  $curl);
echo $err; echo $errmsg;
curl_close($curl);
```

hey i am  trying to get the content in youtube api,but i says could noty resolve,but when i  try via terminal it  returns me the array

Comment: What's the actual error message you get?  Also, your URL isn't valid.  You need to URL-encode the value of `url=` in the query string.

Comment: the error is - error no-06 error-Couldn't resolve host 'www.youtube.com'

Comment: here is what i get on getinfo -Array ( [url] => http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBgn7n3OPAqE&format=json [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove 'o' before embed in url address i.e.

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bgn7n3OPAqE&format=json
```

Comment: Sorry Guys My bad !i didnt had a  working internet on the server!!!I restart apache and  everything Worked like a charm!!!